# Different orientations for diagram and its containers

Tags: wpf, telerik

I'm calling the following layout method on my diagram after I've programmatically added the items:

```
...

var container2 = new RadDiagramContainerShape()
{
    Content = "Status2",
    Items = { ... }
};
myDiagram.Items.Add(container2);

myDiagram.LayoutAsync(settings: new SugiyamaSettings {
    LayoutContainerChildren = true,
    Orientation = Telerik.Windows.Diagrams.Core.Orientation.Vertical
});
```

However, I have several containers in the diagram, and I'd like the items inside them to be oriented horizontally instead of vertically like the containers themselves:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Telerik, at the time of writing it is not possible to have two layouts in one diagram. However, there is a workaround available. You layout the diagram twice, first with

`LayoutContainerChildren = true` and `Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal`,

and again with

`LayoutContainerChildren = false` and `Orientation = Orientation.Vertical`.

This results in:

[image]

http://www.telerik.com/forums/different-orientation-for-container-layout

Answer (score 0):

Either use XAML, or convert this XAML to c#:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: That's a native Orientation property. I need the Telerik UI one (see tag), which is usually used in layout setting for their algorithms.